# CSS priorities don't seem to working

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this in the footer file of a wordpress theme.

```
<div class="footer">
<!-- If you'd like to support WordPress, having the "powered by" link somewhere on your blog is the best way; it's our only promotion or advertising. -->

    <div id="icons">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <p>
    <?php wp_tag_cloud( 'separator= | ' ); ?> 
    </p>
</div>
```

And I want to apply this CSS, which is at the end of my CSS file:

```
#icons ul li a{
    visibility:hidden !important;
}
```

I've tried a dozen variations of the above CSS / HTML and I seem unable to select the links in li elements in the div#icons.

I've tried every trick I know!

Comment: Can't you just delete the link? If you can edit your css, you should be able to edit the theme's footer.php file.

Comment: Are you sure there is no overriding CSS in other, later-loaded stylesheets or CSS embedded in the HTML?

Comment: If you modify some other rules of the stylesheet, do you see your modifications online? After Ctrl-F5, after emptying the cache of your browser? Do you have a proxy at work? Server cache? I guess you're not editing the right file, just a hint. Are there many other !important values in the CSS?

Comment: Thanks for all answers so far. Unfortunately I've either already tried the suggestion or the answer is yes I've already checked that. At this rate I'm going to have to change the div structure and hope that does something.

Comment: Can you give the link to the wordpress page so that one can see this in action? It *should* work as you wrote it. Have you tried looking at the node in something like Firebug?

Comment: @korbinan Sorry for the delay in replying. First, this is currently sitting in my development enivroment, so I can't do that. Second, I hadn't thought of firebug. I'll take a look and report anything interesting.

Comment: @korbinan I firebuged the element in question, which revealed the style rule was not applied. So I looked at the firebug CSS which indicated the rule wasn't even part of the stylesheet. I looked at my source again and discovered I had used hmtl comments instead of CSS ones. I fixed that and it all worked again. So about wraps this question up.

Comment: @YsoL8: You may want to formulate that in a quick answer that you post yourself and then accept, to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is moving that CSS selector to the top of your CSS file, it might be getting overridden by another rule above it.

I created a page using just that code and the wordpress link does not show (but the bullet does) so the CSS you have does select the link and hide it. That is why I think another more specific style might be taking over.

If that doesn't work try making the selector .footer #icons ul li a. And see if that works.

Comment: No, you don't want to move it to the top! CSS is *cascading* - later rules will override earlier rules if the specificity is the same or greater.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. I'd used html comments instead of CSS comments before the style rules with the problem. As these were the last to apply I didn't notice that anything was broken.

Answer (score -1):

`<a>` does not have a visibility property

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

try wrapping your hyperlink with a `<div>`

Comment: or use `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`

Comment: Like any other tag, `<a>` CAN be hidden with `visibility: hidden;` - I think you're getting confused between CSS and HTML properties.